# Product Slider in Category page (description field)

Tags: category, product-list

In the Ultimo theme, the manual says to use this code for a product slider:

```
{{block type="ultimo/product_list_featured"
template="catalog/product/list_featured_slider.phtml" category_id="3" product_count="12"
hide_button="1" block_name="My Products"}}
```

However, if I put this code in a category page (description field), it just outputs the text.

How can I get this code (or something equivalent) to run in that location?

Comment: Debuging a slider is kind of hard, w/o the HTML<head/>/CSS/JS code to see what is present and what is not.

Also check If all the JavaScript libraries, required by the slider are present. If not search for CSS conflicts or lack of classes ... 

If all this is not, then you might have issues requiring JavaScript debug trough the browser console or by the other means.
//Otherwise, I know this is not a direct answer, but I can't buy a 99$ theme, to see the code for myself and I don't have the access to theme from employers .
You should post the relevant code(imho):)

Comment: thanks for the feedback... I wasn't sure if that code was 'standard magento' or specific to ultimo. And if what I was doing, was actually possible.

Answer (score 1):

You have you miss something here's the procedure.

Go to the Category Page you wanted to place the block then go to "Display Settings" Tab and on Display Mode change it to "Static Block and product and lastly select a CMS Block(Make a Static block of Ultimo Featured Products) and Save Category Button.